# Rx: Throttling subscription in Xamarin.Droid project throws missing field 'Ignore' exception from Reactive.Stubs

Tags: c#, xamarin, system.reactive

I've been looking into this Rx issue for several days now and keep drawing a blank so hoping this might ring for somebody. Same subscription works fine when not throttled but as soon as the throttle is added (as below) the exception is thrown. Totally reproducible. Any ideas what 'Ignore' is why it can't be found?

```
_locationManager.LocationChanged.Throttle (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10)).Subscribe (LocationHandle);

{System.MissingFieldException: Field 'System.Reactive.Stubs`1[System.Object].Ignore' not found.
  at System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Disposables.SerialDisposable.set_Disposable (IDisposable value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.Observαble.Throttle`1+_[Android.Locations.Location].OnNext (Android.Locations.Location value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1[Android.Locations.Location].OnNext (Android.Locations.Location value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at rdf.LocationManager.RegisterNewLocation (Android.Locations.Location location) [0x00009] in /Users/xxx/rdf/Rdf/Location/RdfLocationManager.cs:61 }
    Static members: 
    Non-public members: 
    Data: Count=0
    HResult: -2146233071
    HelpLink: (null)
    InnerException: (null)
    Message (System.Exception): "Cannot access a class member."
    Message (System.MissingMemberException): "Member System.Reactive.Stubs`1[System.Object].Ignore not found."
    Message (System.MissingFieldException): "Field 'System.Reactive.Stubs`1[System.Object].Ignore' not found."
    Source: "System.Reactive.Core"
    StackTrace: "  at System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Reactive.Disposables.SerialDisposable.set_Disposable (IDisposable value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Reactive.Linq.Observαble.Throttle`1+_[Android.Locations.Location].OnNext (Android.Locations.Location value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1[Android.Locations.Location].OnNext (Android.Locations.Location value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide a small, complete example that produces this problem?

Comment: What version of Rx are you using? Telling from the name `Observαble` (spot the greek letter, line 5 of your exception trace), it's old. The greek letters have not been in Rx since [this commit](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/commit/dd91d4d8ebc1beb6173a585ece5fb013a237755b)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Observable.Throttle() was not the method I was looking for. Throttle() ignores subsequent messages until the elapsed time has expired. This is subtly different from Observable.Sample() which turned out to do exactly what I was looking for, to sample a rapid sequence into a slower one. The effect of using Throttle() in the manner I did  was that my sequence never started.